# How to change interval colors for effect_plot (jtools) in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, regression, data-visualization

I run a set color scheme for my **R analysis** and want to integrate it into the visualization of my multiple non-linear regression. I am using **`effect_plot()`** from the **`jtools`** package since it is the most convenient function I found.

So far I tried to add **`geom_smooth(se = Light_Blue)`** or **`geom_ribbon(fill = Light_Blue)`**, while setting **`interval = FALSE`** in **`effect_plot()`**, unsuccesfully.

Looking forward to any help!

```
### Visualization of regression

effect_plot(model2, pred = novelty,centered = FALSE, interval = FALSE, colors = Dark_Blue)+
  ggtitle("Title") +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  ylim(0,5)+
  labs(x = "x.text", y= "y.text") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(text=element_text(family="Times", face="bold", size=14), plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 20, b = 0, l = 0)),
        axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 20, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0)),
        )
    
### Color Codes for Plots
    
    Dark_Blue     = "#150563"
    Light_Blue    = "#8ecff5"
    Grey          = "#c2cacf"
```